# How can I display HTML entities in JS? It's always displaying the character

Tags: javascript, entities

I want to display € as `&euro;` but no matter what I try it displays €. I tried already the usual tricks like `&amp;euro;`, even `&amp;&#101;&#117;&#114;&#111;&semi;`, it comes out as €. There is something in the JS that puts it back together.

It's for a little helper tool to generates a MySQL code to copy and paste into a db.

```js
function showData() {
  var theSelect = demoForm.demoSelect;
  var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');
  secondP.innerHTML = ('\',' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
<form name="demoForm">
  <select name="demoSelect" onchange="showData()">
    <option value=" 'Australia','AUD','A$' ">Australia</option>
    <option value=" 'Austria','EUR','&amp;&#101;&#117;&#114;&#111;&semi;' ">Austria</option>
    <option value=" 'Ireland','EUR','&euro;' ">Ireland</option>
    <option value=" 'Philippines','PHP','&#x20B1;' ">Philippines</option>
    <option value=" 'Poland','PLN','z&#321;' ">Poland</option>
    <option value=" 'Russia','RUB','&#8381;' ">Russia</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p>



  <span id="secondP"></span>
```

Comment: what does this means btw *I want to display € as &euro;*? you don't want to show € sign?

Comment: Correct, because it generates a code and I want to input `&euro;` into the db and not €.

Comment: @Guy Incognito - that works fine. Thank you! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from a commenting user that then deleted his comment. So don't give me credit:

I had to change `innerHTML` to `innerText` and then write `&euro;` as `&amp;euro;`

Works perfectly!

http://jsfiddle.net/yello/gp56Ljas/9/